# Calculating floodplain percentage in parcel dataset

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, parcel

I have parcel data for an entire county and a floodplain that lies on top of it. I would like to isolate the 100 year portion of the floodplain and calculate how much of it is within each parcel.

Answer (score 1):

definition query to find only the 100 year portion of the flood plain.  then there are several options,  the foundation is described here, as well as some tools others have created.

http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=982&t=271929

Quoted from esri.com ,just in case the link dies, by user Ken Carrier.  FYI he is dealing with soil types in parcels whereas you are dealing with flood plains but the concept is the exact same.

> Here is how I worked the code;
>
> 1. Work with a selected parcel polygon
> 2. Export select parcel polygon to shapefile, add to map.
> 3. Select by location any soil polygons that intersect with the export parcel polygon
> 4. Export the selected soil polygons to a shapefile, add the new shapefile to the map.
> 5. Clip the soils layer so that only the soil polygons that are within the parcel polygon remain, this clip code creates a new shapefile and
>      adds it to the map.
> 6. We then dissolved the clip_results shapefile by attributes, so that if I had 2 "A" type soils polygons and 2 "B" type soils polygons,
>      after the dissolve I would only have 1 "A" and 1 "B" type polygon in
>      the attribute table, basically a merge on the polygons by attribute.
>      We did this so we could calculate acreage on unique soil types versus
>      calculating the acreage on each polygon.
> 7. This dissolve code also creates a new shapefile and adds it to the map, so then we add a new field to the shapefile and calculate
>      acreage, then we select all features from the dissolved shapefile and
>      export the results to an excel spreadsheet, which opens up after it
>      has been created.
> 8. Then we label the features, and put a transparency on the dissolve layer.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to approach this would be to select the 100 year floodplain and save that as a new layer using Data Export in ArcMap (right-click the layer in the Table of Contents). Then, for step 3 (read below for step 2), you will do a Union (in the Geoprocessing Menu) of the 100 year floodplain layer and the parcels. What you get from that is a combined parcels and floodplain layer with all the fields from both layers. Fields from the floodplain layer in areas with no 100-year floodplain will have a -1 in the field.

**Step 2.** Assuming you have area calculated for the parcels when you begin (this is automatic if the layer is in a GDB) then you can add a new field (use a double or a float; lets call it OLD_AREA) and **BEFORE** you do the Union operation calculate the new field (OLD_AREA) to the value of Area field (or just use "Calculate Geometry" it should be the same at this point).

**Step 3.** Do the Union operation

**Step 4.** Recalculate area in the original Area field (**NOT** OLD_AREA).

**Step 5.** Add a new field to represent the percentage of original size (call it PCT_ORIG for example) and calculate that to ([SHAPE_AREA] / [OLD_AREA]) * 100 **BUT** do this only on the selected subset of parcels where the values (in some field from the floodplain layer) do NOT = -1.

Parcels that have any floodplain in them will have a percentage calculated for them based out of the original 100%. If necessary, you could join this result (using just the subset where floodplain exists) back to the original parcels layer based on a unique ID from the parcels.